# What's the time complexity of it?

Tags: time-complexity

I wrote a pseducode for the Algorithm I am interested in its time complexity.
Here is algorithm:

```
SolveDominoes(n, dominoes_data):
ListA
for dominoes in dominoes_data:
    ListA.add(dominoes)
ListP = Red Domino from starting domino
for(int i = 1; i < n; i *= 2)
      ListB = ListA.copy()
      ListC
      Sort(ListA, ListA.second)
      Sort(ListB, ListB.first)
      Sort(ListP)
      ItA = A.start(), ItB = ListB.start(), itP = ListP.start()
      while (ItA or ItB or ItP != end)
         if(ItB1 = itA2)
             ListC.add((a1, b2))
             ItA++, ItB++
        else if (b1 = p1)
             ListP.front(b2, p1 + i)
             ItA++, ItP++
        else if b1 > p1
            ItP++
        else if b1 > a2
           ItA
ListA = ListC
```

I tried to calculate it, I calculated it to be O( n (log n) ^2) due to O(log n) for the for loop and then O(n log n)  of sorting. So(log n * n log n) is it correct?

Comment: I'm not clear on all of the definitions here, since it's pseudocode; are the number of dominoes in dominoes_data constant, and is n like a number of turns or players?  In other words, does the length of ListA depend at all on the value of n?

Comment: @Vaekor yes. It relative to the number of deminoes.